# Grails - how execute code before every save?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

Is there a good/standard way to execute some common code before every `save()` invocation on domain classes?

For example, my domain

```
class Page {

    String url
    Boolean processed
    Date date
    Integer urlCrc 
}
```

My form has only 3 first fields and I would like to calculate `urlCrc` every time the `save()` method is called. I cannot just override save method because it is injected.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use GORM events - see the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping).  Since by default `validate()` is called before every `save()` I would use that.

```
class Page {
    //your defs here

    def beforeValidate() {
        this.urlCrc = yourComputationHere
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Unfortunately grails.org is down, due to some routing problems 
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Is-the-plugin-repository-down-td4628824i40.html so I needed ask here

Comment: The above solution is probably best, but another option is to use a grails calculated field.  See the docs for that.

Comment: If you want to execute the code before the save use `beforeUpdate() / beforeInsert()`. if you use `beforeValidate()` that it's called always when you call `validate()` (method `save()` call 'validate()' before save). So your code it's executed before validate even if you don't save.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Page {
    def beforeInsert() {
        this.beforeUpdate()
    }
    def beforeUpdate() {
        this.urlCrc = 'calculate something'
    }
}
```

Comment: can you link to the documentation on this?

Comment: Yes, this is the [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/1.3.6/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.5%20Advanced%20GORM%20Features)

Answer (score 1):

This topic is covered in the GORM docs:

6.5 Advanced GORM Features

[6.5.1 Events and Auto Timestamping](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping)